# Использование robokassa в mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с трудностью, и не знаю с какой стороны подойти.
Ориентируясь на пример для perl с официального сайта, написал следующий примитивный код, который однако не работает.

В шаблон вставлен такой код:

```html
        <div><script language=JavaScript
       src='https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/PaymentForm/FormFLS.js?MerchantLogin=<%= $Robo->{mrh_login} %>&DefaultSum=<%= $Robo->{def_sum} %>&InvId=<%= $Robo->{inv_id} %>&Description=<%= $Robo->{inv_desc} %>&SignatureValue=<%= $Robo->{crc} %>&shp_Item=<%= $Robo->{shp_item} %>&Culture=<%= $Robo->{culture} %>&Encoding=<%= $Robo->{encoding} %>'></script></div>
```

На бакэнде:

```
sub donate {
my $self = shift;

my $mrh_login = "demo";
my $mrf_pass1 = "password_1";
my $inv_id = 0;
my $inv_desc = "Консультационные услуги от ROBOKASSA";

my $def_sum = "10";
my $shp_item = "2";
my $culture = "ru";
my $encoding = "utf-8";

my $crc = md5_hex("$mrh_login::$inv_id:$mrf_pass1:shp_Item=$shp_item");

$self->render(Robo => { mrh_login => $mrh_login,
            mrf_pass1 => $mrf_pass1,
            inv_id => $inv_id,
            inv_desc => $inv_desc,
            def_sum  => $def_sum,
            shp_item => $shp_item,
            culture =>  $culture,
            encoding => $encoding,
            crc => $crc});
}
```

Во первых я получаю ругательство на

```
md5_hex("$mrh_login::$inv_id:$mrf_pass1:shp_Item=$shp_item");
```

в которой первая переменная интерпретируется как $mrh_login::, т.е. к имени прилипают ::, чего не происходит при вызове данной функции из чистого перла (вне фреймворка mojo), сделал по этому поводу хак вида

```
md5_hex("$mrh_login:".":"."$inv_id:$mrf_pass1:shp_Item=$shp_item");
```

что конечно не отменяет проблемы, вопрос -- это баг моджо или я что-то не понял?
Но, даже если я передаю в функции javascript уже готовые значения, посчитанные в чистом перле, то результат тот же:

```
invalid parameter: Signature.
```

Я ведь правильно понимаю, что для демоскрипта используется логин и пароль такие как у меня в скрипте?
Тогда вопрос, может кто-нибудь привести пример рабочего кода/вызова робокассы с сайта, на перле.

[image: ошибка]

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать этим: `$mrh_login::`? И при чём тут Mojo?

Comment: Функция вида: md5_hex("$mrh_login::$inv_id:$mrf_pass1:shp_Item=$shp_item"); Без проблем выполняется в перле, но при её выове в теле функции Mojo возникает ошибка: Use of uninitialized value $mrh_login:: in concatenation (.) or string at /mnt/data/projs/ext/web/maxbionic/max_bionic_ws/script/../lib/MaxBionicWS/Controller/Pages.pm line 100.
 Т.е. имя переменной почему-то берётся как $mrh_login::

Comment: Есть мысль, что конструкция `$mrh_login::` рассматривается как `typeglob`... Но чтобы понять нужно больше контекста (см. [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))